# Parameter names for Dapper multi-item Execute

Tags: dapper

With this code using Dapper `.Execute`:

```cs
using var c = new SqlConnection(ccstr);
var lst = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
c.Execute("select @p", lst); // @p not recognized as parameter name
```

Is there a way to have a parameter name (here `@p`) for this native object list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leverage anonymous objects

```
using var c = new SqlConnection(ccstr);
var lst = new[] { 
  new {p = 1}, 
  new {p = 2} 
  new {p = 3} };
c.Execute("select @p", lst);
```

Comment: Yeah, `var lst = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Select(p => new { p });` works, but `ugly++`